# How to drive object's local transform by another object, while relative to third object?

Tags: constraints, drivers

That title is probably a bit confusing so lemme try to explain what I mean:

Let's say I have two objects: *Object A* and *Object B*, and two cameras: *Camera A* and *Camera B*.

I want the position and rotation of Camera B relative to Object B to be the same as the position and rotation of Camera A relative to Object A.

Here's a visual representation of what I'm trying to do, with the two objects and cameras:
[image: 1]

I've tried experimenting with different combinations of drivers and constraints, but I wasn't able to get it to work. If anyone could help me out it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is probably a way to do this with constraints. In particular, the transformation constraint, which will let you map, say, the x axis of one object to the z axis of another object.

Comment: let me get it more clearly, suppose you drag one cam to the Right angle, do you want the other to appear in that same location but at the other arm?

Comment: @Neail I guess so yeah.

Comment: then you need a 3rd object constain cameras to that. disable that 3rd object in render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with drivers and parenting.

1. Use *Rightclick > Copy New Driver* and then *RMB > Paste Driver*
2. Drive all location and rotation fields from *Camera A* to *Camera B*  (so they match perfectly)
3. Select *Camera B* and go *Object Properties > Relations > Parent* and target *Object B*

<sup>2. *RMB > Copy Driver > Paste Driver* from *Camera A* to *Camera B*. Do this for each location/rotation field.</sup> 
[image]

<sup>3. In Object Properties of *Camera B*, target Object B.

Camera B will now inherit Object B rotation/location, but will also keep the driven position and rotation on top of that.</sup>
[image]

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Great, I was a bit worried I didn't explain it well enough :). Good luck with your project.